# twitter feeds using json array

Tags: android, json, twitter

I am developing an application to retrieve Twitter feeds. I wrote the following

```
try {   
    codeString x = "";
    Twitter y;
    HttpClient pingclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost pingpost = new HttpPost("https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/krish_hari.json");
    pingpost.addHeader("Accepts", "application/json");
    pingpost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    org.apache.http.HttpResponse pingResponse = pingclient.execute(pingpost);
    HttpEntity loginEntity = pingResponse.getEntity();
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(loginEntity);

    //InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsontwitter);
    //byte [] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    //while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
    //String jsontext = new String(buffer);
    JSONArray entries = new JSONArray(result);

    x = "JSON parsed.\nThere are [" + entries.length() + "]\n\n";

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<entries.length();i++) {
        JSONObject post = entries.getJSONObject(i);
        x += "------------\n";
        x += "Date:" + post.getString("created_at") + "\n";
        x += "Post:" + post.getString("text") + "\n\n";
    }
    tvData.setText(x);
}
catch (Exception je) {
    tvData.setText("Error w/file: " + je.getMessage());
}
```

I get the error *`error w/file:twitter.com`*. Can anyone help me to crack this?

Comment: In which line is the exception thrown? If you don't know, try to debug it step by step.

Comment: @user1002448 Did you checked my post?

Comment: @ Paresh Mayani Its not used..forgot to delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code to retrieve Twitter feed:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url[0]));
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
try
{
    String line = null;             
    while ((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append('\n');                
    }
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String jsontext = new String(sb.toString());
```

`url[0]` is the URL to the JSON feed.

You must reformat your URL, this format you're using now is deprecated.

Refer to https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

Some advices, it may works:

1. Use HTTPGet instead of HTTPPost
2. No need to addHeader, remove those both 2 lines

try these out and let me know:

Comment: Exception is in org.apache.http.HttpResponse pingResponse = pingclient.execute(pingpost);

Comment: just try http instead of https in URL, use HTTPGet

Comment: Tried that too...Still the same trouble

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Check the Response in Log cat

```
 public class List extends Activity  {
    String response_data;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new Load_Task().execute();
    }

    public class Load_Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(List.this);
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              try{
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
                String getURL = "http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/krish_hari.json";
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
                if (resEntityGet != null) {  
                    response_data=EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
                }
                Log.v("aaaa", ""+response_data);

              }
             catch (Exception e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
             if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                 this.dialog.dismiss();
             }
        }
    }
       }
```

Comment: I HAD GIVEN LIKE THIS http://pastebin.com/b9JhCxqu. please check if it is what you meant

Comment: @user1002448 Remove https and put http

Comment: 11-02 19:05:21.686: WARN/System.err(1300): java.net.UnknownHostException: twitter.com
11-02 19:05:21.706: WARN/System.err(1300):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
11-02 19:05:21.747: WARN/System.err(1300):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
11-02 19:05:21.796: WARN/System.err(1300):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
11-02 19:05:21.816: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)

Comment: 11-02 19:05:21.865: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-02 19:05:21.886: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-02 19:05:21.886: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
11-02 19:05:21.896: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)

Comment: @user1002448 UnknownHostException Means problem in connection with Twitter..try after some time

Comment: 11-02 19:05:21.905: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-02 19:05:21.916: WARN/System.err(1300):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-02 19:05:21.926: WARN/System.err(1300):     at com.msi.xmlvsjson.xmlvsjson$Load_Task.doInBackground(xmlvsjson.java:87)
11-02 19:05:21.926: WARN/System.err(1300):     at com.msi.xmlvsjson.xmlvsjson$Load_Task.doInBackground(xmlvsjson.java:1)

Comment: @Venky..ok will try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add `android.permission.INTERNET`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```